# Same color looks different for two widgets

Tags: python, pyqt5

In the following code the same background color looks different for two different widgets (`QProgressBar` and `QPushButton`).

What's the reason for that?

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of MainWindow]

main.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        loadUi("mainwindow.ui", self)
        self.progressBar.setStyleSheet(f"background-color: {QColor('red').name()}")


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

mainwindow.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>200</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="locale">
   <locale language="English" country="UnitedKingdom"/>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
      <item row="0" column="0">
       <widget class="QProgressBar" name="progressBar">
        <property name="value">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="1">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>200</width>
          <height>0</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true">background-color: red;</string>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Button</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>28</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @user9402680 I'm using Linux (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        loadUi("mainwindow_.ui", self)

        self.progressBar.setStyleSheet(f"""
            background-color: {QColor('red').name()}; 
            border: 1px solid black;
            text-align: top;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 12px;            
        """) 
        self.progressBar.setValue(24)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: In my case your fix doesn't change the background colors of `QProgressBar` and `QPushButton`.